# Adding a widget to the bottom of a window without resizing other widgets

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt application that is mainly a set of buttons. I would to have a QTextEdit window at the bottom that is hidden by default, but the user can toggle off and on. The problem I'm encountering, however, is that when the user turns the TextEdit widget on, the buttons resize. I would like all the buttons to remain the same and the state of the QTextEdit to not visually affect anything. The first image is how I always want the buttons to look, regardless if the TextEdit is toggled on or off. The second is how it looks when I hide the TextEdit and I want it to NOT do this.

[image]

[image]

My code:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        for i in range(5):
            btn = QPushButton()
            btn.setText("Button:" + str(i+1))
            btn.clicked.connect(self.toggle_log)
            self.main_layout.addWidget(btn)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.console = QTextEdit()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.console)
        self.show()

    def toggle_log(self):
        if self.console.isHidden():
            self.console.show()
        else:
            self.console.hide()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution is to recalculate the sizes an instant after being shown or hidden:

```py
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.central_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.central_widget)
        for i in range(5):
            btn = QPushButton()
            btn.setText("Button:" + str(i + 1))
            btn.clicked.connect(self.toggle_log)
            self.main_layout.addWidget(btn)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.console = QTextEdit()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.console)
        self.show()

    def toggle_log(self):
        if self.console.isHidden():
            QTimer.singleShot(0, self.resize_show)
            self.console.show()
        else:
            self.central_widget.updateGeometry()
            QTimer.singleShot(0, self.resize_hide)
            self.console.hide()

    def resize_show(self):
        self.resize(self.width(), self.sizeHint().height())

    def resize_hide(self):
        self.resize(self.width(), self.minimumSizeHint().height())
```

Comment: This looks like it works, but why do you use `singleShot`? Why doesn't this code work without it?

Comment: @Snuh Qt does not apply the window changes directly but uses the eventloop to do it, for example the show method does not make the window instantly visible but instead tells the OS to make it visible, the same for the geometry change. And the functions that I use need that the changes are already applied, so I use singleShot and the 0 indicates that it is executed after the commands that are already in the queue (for example the change of geometry)